# Unable to install Windows 2008R2 x64 on HP ProLiant ML 150 G6 with Smart Array B110i

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am installing Windows 2008 R2 x64 (Microsoft OEM version) on a HP ProLiant ML 150 with Smart Array B110i controller. I load the B110i drivers from a USB thumbdrive, Windows Setup can create, delete and format correctly the partitions on the raidset, but when I exit the disk manager to start setup, Windows says that he cannot find a primary partition to install Windows.

The EasySetup disk provided with the system does not support Windows 2008 R2 x64 Microsoft OEM. I downloaded the latest version of EasySetup from HP website, but does not support Windows 2008 R2 x64 Microsoft OEM.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Im going thru the same problems. Were you able to work it out? What was the exact process used? After enabling the controller thru the Bios, did you just directly install Windows using the USB key mentioned above?

Comment: @Reido, since Irosa hasn't been seen for a month, I doubt he's coming back soon. He didn't make any mention of BIOS settings. It looks like he used the USB Tool from MS to make a USB installation media from a DVD installation media. See the download link he provided in his answer.

Comment: The exact process is to follow Microsoft instructions for the tool to create a bootable USB key, then you boot from USB and proceed in the same way you would do with DVD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP Support provided me the explanation and a solution. The explanation is that hard drives and DVD reader are "on the same bus", so Windows gets confused. The solution is to download [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool) and create an USB installation key with it.